# How do I get the previous <div> element text using jQuery()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the last previous div element using jQuery()?  The ID of the element after the one I'm looking for is 'A0.R0.Work Phone #'.

Here is what the HTML looks like...

```
<td class="fl flu">
    <div id="ap_cv_valid" style="float: left; display: block; ">
        V
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        Primary Phone #
    </div>
</td>
<td class="fv fvu" style="padding-left: 6px; cursor: text;" id="A0.R0.Work Phone #"></td>
```

What I'm using now is...

```
var location = 'td[id^="A0.R0.Work"]'
var last = jQuery(location).prev(function(){
    jQuery('div:last').text()
});
```

I'm looking for last to contain the text string 'Primary Phone #' only.

Got any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clean this up by removing any code that doesn't demonstrate your problem?  Also, check out the $.prev jQuery function: http://jqapi.com/#p=prev

Comment: Good luck using an id value that has a space in it.  That's a lot more difficult to work with in jQuery.  You really ought to not have spaces in your ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

HTML:

```
​<table>
  <td class="fl flu">
    <div id="ap_cv_valid" style="float: left; display: block; ">
    V
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
      Primary Phone #
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="fv fvu" style="padding-left: 6px; cursor: text;" id="A0.R0.Work">Phone #</td>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var last = $('td#A0\\.R0\\.Work').prev().find('div:last');
console.log(last.text());
```

`​​​​​​​​​​Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DkB9t/

Note that it's bad if the element id contains spaces, and it's better not to include "." as well.  If you need to have either space or "." in you id, you'll have to escape it with "\\"

Answer (score 0):

check this

http://jsfiddle.net/3XuRT/